# wp_list_comments renders incorrectly nested <ul>

Tags: comments

I'm trying to figure out how `wp_list_comments` works. So I made the simplest possible `callback` just to see the structure of the result:

```
function custom_comments_callback( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        Hello!
    </li>
    <?php
    }
```

I thought this function would be structurally correct but the result seems to contain incorrectly nested `<ul>` elements:

[image]

I thought an `<ul>` in an `<ul>` always **had to** be enclosed in a `<li>` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129037/correct-semantics-for-ul-in-ul) for instance. Should I modify my `callback` function or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Your callback should not include a closing `</li>` tag, the comment walker adds these as and when necessary.

Comment: @t31os: thanks, good catch! Completely overlooked that. Problem solved.

Comment: Happy to help. :)